# LINQ Include is excluding some records even though it is supposed to be a OUTER JOIN

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq

This query returns 3 results with the property Completed missing even if the item has a Completed object

```
db.WishlistItems.ToList
```

This query returns the 1 result that has the Completed property set

```
db.WishlistItems.Include("Completed").ToList
```

I want to return all three records but one should have the Completed property populated with the associated object. How do I do that?

The EF object property is defined as

```
<Required> Public Property Completed As UserLog
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Completed` is defined as required? Then `Completed` cannot be null. Entity Framework will most likely translate this into `INNER JOIN`.

In order to return all entries you'll need to remove the `<required>` attribute.